# How can I return a classvalue in a method (angular

Tags: angular

I would like to return a `ClassValue` like in Java (`RandomClass.class`).
In my case, I want to make an flexible

```
Observable<SomethingThatChangesWhileRuntime>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a Generic type. You could have an `Observable<number>` which is a stream of numbers, or an `Observable<SomeCustomType>` which is a stream of some custom defined type.

Read more on generic types here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Using generic types in an example method, returning an Observable:

```
function makeObservable<T>(x: T): Observable<T> {
  return Observable.of(x);
}

interface Data {
  [key: string]: string;
}

makeObservable<Data>({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'});
```

Comment: Happy to help :)